# Error while compressing the decimal value (val: 0.6 => val:0,6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild-task, yui-compressor

To compress Javascript and CSS files I am using Yahoo for a solution. Net (http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/)

**I have an object:**

```
defaults = {  
    html: "",  
    opacity: 0.6,  
    loadOnDemand: true,  
    showEffect: "fade",  
    hideEffect: "fade"
};
```

Note the value 0.6

**Result after compression:**

```
defaults = {
    html : "",
    opacity : 0,
    6,
    loadOnDemand : true,
    showEffect : "fade",
    hideEffect : "fade"
};
```

I am using the task (MSBuild) for Visual Studio to compress my JS.

**The following XML code:**

```
<CompressorTask
    CssFiles="@(CssFiles)"
    CssOutputFile="$(cssFile)"
    CssCompressionType="YuiStockCompression"
    PreserveCssComments="false"
    JavaScriptFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)"
    ObfuscateJavaScript="false"
    PreserveAllSemicolons="true"
    DisableOptimizations="Nope"
    JavaScriptOutputFile="$(jsFile)"
    LoggingType="ALittleBit"
    IsEvalIgnored="false" />
```

Full code in: https://gist.github.com/1817326

looking for an answer, found this thread: http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/discussions/243522

But did not help me much